# Is $A$ ill conditioned matrix?

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ with is its $LU$-decomposition such that $A=LU$ and suppose that $U$ is ill conditioned ($\left \| U \right \|\left \| U^{-1} \right \|$ is large) , does it mean that $A$ is ill conditioned ?

Comment: Does the double bar denote spectral norm?

Comment: It is an  induced norm , i think they're the same , spectral and induced

Comment: Are you only interested for square matrices $A$?

Comment: yes square matrices

Comment: Sorry last question - Is there some sort of constraint on $L$ and $U$? Sometimes people take $U$ to be unipotent (diagonal entries are all one).

Comment: no , there is no such thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if simply we consider $$A=\left[\matrix{1&0\cr0&1}\right],\quad
L=\left[\matrix{10^n&0\cr0&10^{-n}}\right],\quad U=\left[\matrix{10^{-n}&0\cr0&10^{n}}\right]?$$
Clearly $L$ is lower triangular, $U$ is upper triangular, $A=LU$ and
$$\hbox{cond}_2(A)=1,\quad\hbox{cond}_2(L)=\hbox{cond}_2(U)=10^{2n}.$$